# How to set one table's field based on value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables.  The first contains a list of ID's. The second has a larger list of ID's.  I want to update the second table ONLY if it doesn't exist in the first.  This isn't catching all of them:

```
UPDATE TableB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA
ON TableB.id = TableA.id
SET TableB.Status = "Inactive"
WHERE TableB.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, assuming that `TableB` is the "second" table:

```
UPDATE TableB b LEFT OUTER JOIN
       TableA a
       ON b.id = a.id
    SET b.Status = 'Inactive'
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
------^
```

Your `WHERE` clause referenced the wrong table.